# Notation for Function Composed with Projection Mapping

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a mapping $f: A \to B^n$.  Is there a notation/standard way to define for the mapping $f_i: A \to B$, which is the $i$th coordinate of $f$, i.e. $f$ composed with the projection mapping of the $i$th coordinate?  Something like saying "$f_i$ is the $i$th coordinate of $f$?"

Also, in the other direction, suppose I have $m$ functions $f_i:A \to B$, and I want to define a mapping $f: A \to B^m$ such that 
$f(x) = (f_1(x),...,f_m(x))$.  Is there better notation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already indicated the standard notation, which is $f_i$. In particular, this is a [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) in some category of sets, so it comes equipped with natural projections $\pi_i$ so that for every $f:Y \to B^n$, there is some $f_i:Y \to B_i$ that factors through the projection.